# Rails 3 error: no such file to load -- initializer (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm on Ubuntu and my app is written for Rails 2.3.5 and I got it to run on 2.3.10 but when I upgraded to Rails 3.0.3 and tried to run it using "ruby script/server", it throws this error.

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in `activate': can't activate rails (= 2.3.10, runtime) for [], already activated rails-3.0.3 for [] (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from /home/bob/savage/config/boot.rb:55:in `load_initializer'
        from /home/bob/savage/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
        from /home/bob/savage/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
        from /home/bob/savage/config/boot.rb:110
        from script/server:2:in `require'
        from script/server:2
```

When I uninstalled Rails 2.3.10, it throws this error instead

```
bob@ubuntu:~/test.2.3.10$ ruby script/server
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: rails(3.0.3 not = 2.3.10) (Gem::LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
        from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
        from /home/bob/test.2.3.10/config/boot.rb:60:in `load_rails_gem'
        from /home/bob/test.2.3.10/config/boot.rb:54:in `load_initializer'
        from /home/bob/test.2.3.10/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
        from /home/bob/test.2.3.10/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
        from /home/bob/test.2.3.10/config/boot.rb:114
        from script/server:2:in `require'
        from script/server:2
```

Ideas? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What did you do to upgrade from Rails 2 to 3? Have you got a Gemfile? Are you using Bundler and have you executed "bundle install" ?

Comment: +1 Scott Lowe. How'd you upgrade? Did you just clone Rails to vendor/rails? This is what it looks like to me.

Comment: I simply ran "gem install rails" to upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Hey, I know it's been a while, but I thought I should add that your application won't run if you simply install the latest v3 Rails gems because Rails 3 has had some major architectural changes made to it. There are a number of changes that you need to make to your code in order to upgrade your app. Help is here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#upgrading-to-rails-3

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error until I realized that I was still using the same old config/boot.rb from the 2.3.10 version of my app.  I went into a clean directory and generated a new Rails 3.0.3 app and used the boot.rb it created.  The file is totally different, and it got me past this error.

Comment: boot.rb, environment.rb and route.rb had to be updated to get my app back online. http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/  outlines the changes with route.rb.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

After reading the comments above, I tried creating a new, empty application in another directory:

     rails new foo

     cd foo

     rails s

WEBrick starts up just fine.  Perhaps Bob can duplicate this?  This rules out problems with Rails and Ruby versions (3.0.3, 187p302 respectively for me).  And it really points to problems with running Rails 3 utilities in directories with old versions of boot.rb or environment.rb, and running Rails 2 script files (plugin, server) once 3.0.3 is the active version of Rails.

Comment: Confirmed, creating a new Rails 3.0 app works fine. I had the same thought that something like boot.rb is causing the conflict but not sure exactly what.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default Rails 3.0.0 config/boot.rb file.  I would use all or parts of this instead of your config/boot.rb

```
require 'rubygems'

# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Noticed 1.8 in your path - I believe you'll need to be on 1.9.2 for Rails 3 to work. Use RVM to get this up and running right away.

Additionally - you typically start Rails 3 with 'rails server' or 'rails s' - you don't need to fire off script/server anymore. Give that a go and see how it works.

Comment: I have Ruby 1.8.7 installed, Rails 3 supports that version according to docs http://rubyonrails.org/download

Comment: And if you fire off 'rails s' or 'rails server' do you see the same error as documented in original post?

Comment: That command gives me instructions on how create a new Rails app

Comment: You don't need to be on 1.9.2 to run Rails 3, 1.8.7p302 will work fine.

Comment: @Ryan, that's my understanding as well but does it have to be a particular patch or will any version of 1.8.7 work? Mine is p249.

Comment: @bob - if rails s/server is trying to build a new app then your rails binary isn't 3.x. Try a 'which' on rails and see if you are in fact looking at 3...

Comment: Assuming you mean the command "which rails", it points to /usr/bin/rails. If it helps, "rails -v" returns "Rails 3.0.3" which I would think means I'm using the right version.

Comment: You're close in your first scenario but something is loading in 2.3.10 - it's either vendor/rails as Ryan indicated above or it's possible that 2.3.10 is referenced in config/environment.rb? If so, gut it...

Comment: @Bob: It needs to be anything *above* p249. 249 has been known to break Rails. I'd advise just upgrading to 1.9.2.

Comment: @Ryan, unfortunately upgrading to 1.9.2 is not an option currently since I need to run it on Heroku and they don't support 1.9.2 yet.